# Laravel vendor autoloading doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, package, composer-php

Currently, I am new on package development, and have a hard time on creating a new package. To the point, I want to make a new package, but the autoload (PSR-4 and classmap) seems not working. I get class not found exception. I tried to find the answer to my question everywhere, but still have not found any help.

Here is my composer.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "imamassi/tree",
  "description": "Tree generator from an array/object with parent id",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Imam Assidiqqi",
      "email": "assidiqqi.imam@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {},
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
      "Imamassi\\": "src/"
    },
    "classmap":["src/"]
  }
}
```

My package directory:
[image: Package directory]

It already took me for several hours just to figure how to make this work, hope I'll find the answer here :)

NB: I already done dump-autoload for several times, still can't make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The autoloading path must lead to the exact directory where the namespace is used.

That means for your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Imamassi\\": "src/Imamassi"
    }
}
```

After changing the main `composer.json`'s autoload section, don't forget to rebuild autoloading cache via:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: but I want to load the Tree.php (src/tree.php) file

Comment: This will load every class with this namespace in that directory.